# How to find MSE between 2 np arrays when 1 array contains nans

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a custom loss function exactly like MSE, except that it will not count predictions where the truth is 0 (or below some threshold). My idea to solve this is to use `np.nan`'s to essentially ignore and not count those predictions. However, neither of my methods for finding MSE work with `np.nan`'s.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

a = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
b = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))

##### METHOD 1 
# Find initial MSE 
difference_array = np.subtract(a,b)
squared_array = np.square(difference_array)
mse = squared_array.mean()

##### METHOD 2 
mse = mean_squared_error(a,b)

# Now, I place nan wherever a < 0.5
c=a
c[abs(c)<=0.5] = np.nan

# to test that the MSE is different, compute MSE using method 1 or 2
# but this throws errors for both methods
mse = mean_squared_error(c,b)
```

Is there an alternate way I could get MSE but ignoring all predictions where the truth is 0? The reason I do this is because basic MSE causes the neural net to be really good at predicting 0, but I'm more interested in how well it predicts positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `np.where`. Then just discard the rows (temporarily) below your threshold.

So, we have:

```py
a = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
b = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
temp_a = a[np.where(a>0.5)] # Your threshold condition
temp_b = b[np.where(a>0.5)]
mean_squared_error(temp_a, temp_b)
```

This essentially removes rows where the value is less than your threshold, and then calculates the MSE.